Angular web white screen
I created my website using Angular 14, and it runs smoothly on all modern browsers. However, when accessing it from smart TVs, I encounter a persistent issue where the screen remains white. I've attempted to address this by switching to ES5 compatibility, but unfortunately, the problem persists. Could anyone please offer assistance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

can you give a example of a TV model and the browser used in it ?

and does "all modern browsers" include mobile browsers?

Kaperto i am using samsung tv and their default browser name as Internet

Ja Da yes working on mobile browsers
